# Prompt on Button Press

Tags: android, prompt

I'm currently working on the part of an app that would let the user register and input his/her details. I would want to display a "Successfully Registered!" prompt or message after the user presses the submit button just so the user knows that the details he/she inputted were submitted.

Here's my submit button:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Intent recvdIntent = getIntent();
        mUsername = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        mUsername = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD");

        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        submitUserData();
                        return;
                        }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Use `Toast` or `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AlertDialog**

```
public void showAlertDialog(String title,String msg){


    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AlertDialogActivity.this)
            .setTitle(title)  // Setting Dialog Title
            .setMessage(msg)// Setting Dialog Message
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create();

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });


    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

**Toast.**

```
public static void showToast(Context context,String msg){

        Toast.makeText(context,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try out this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setTitle("Success");
builder.setMessage("Successfully registered, Sign in now");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: Tip: You can chain those... for example `new Builder().setCancelable(false).setTitle().show()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm currently trying out this one. However, I'm quite confused on the "Intent intent = new Intent...." line. The name of the activity where the Registration happens is RegisterActivity. So to where do I substitute it, to SignupActivity or TargetActivity? Also, I'm getting cannot resolve symbol errors.

Comment: Hi AndyMarty, sorry for the late response, the intent is used to navigate between two activities in android. if you want to move the user from current activity to another activity you need to use the intent. as you said your current activity is RegisterActivity you need to do like this   Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);  Here the TargetActivity.class is the activity you need to move the user. its your wish its not compulsory to use intent in pop-up message you can place your code in place of intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways ,

1. Alert Dialog
2. Toast
3. Popup Dialog

Let's do it using Alert Dialog .

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Why not `set` things on the `Builder`?

Comment: Not getting you sir!

Comment: See other answer and my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/42849467/2308683

Comment: This is just a sample , you can modify this as per your need . It means you can set title ,message ,icon etc dynamically as you want .